# Automatic Code Generation C# User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I wrote a new component in C# for DriveComboBox 
(It inherits from ImageComboBox - component that was found on the internet), see code example:

```
public class DriveComboBox : ImageComboBox.ImageComboBox
{
    public DriveComboBox()
        : base()
    {
        foreach (ImageComboBoxItem item in allImageComboBoxItems)
        {
           this.Items.Add(item);                
        }
    }
}
```

This partial code adds into the control the drives and after this control is dragged into the form, the items are added to the designer of the code of the form.
The problem is that once the program is run, items are added by the code above and then the designer code adds them again, so we end up with double items.

The question is where should the place for adding the items be in the control or how to prevent the designer from adding them again ?

Comment: What is an `ImageComboBox`?

Comment: @DavidG This is an extended, owner drawn ComboBox which has an added support to display images in the combobox dropdown as well
as the edit (text) box.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ImageComboBoxControl.aspx?display=Print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem it seems the "visual ??" designer from visual studio can use runtime code as designtime code.
I dont understand complete what is going on but I did managed to avoid the problem with this method :

```
protected bool IsInDesignMode
{
    get { return DesignMode || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime; }
}
```

which I use like this :

```
public DriveComboBox()
    : base()
{
    if (IsInDesignMode == false)
    {
        foreach (ImageComboBoxItem item in allImageComboBoxItems)
        {
           this.Items.Add(item);                
        }
    }
}
```